# Updating d3 donut chart from v4 to v5

Tags: d3.js

I'm updating some d3.js code from v4.13.0 to v5.7.0.

I can't see whats changed between the version numbers in terms of this chart type and I'm stumped. https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#arcs

What am I missing here?

And any general advice on code improvements for this snippet are also much appreciated.

Many thanks,

O'Malley

```
  $rootScope.drawInfo = (data, parent, status) => {

    const svg = d3.select(parent);
    svg.selectAll("path").remove();
    svg.selectAll("text").remove();

    const backgroundColors = ["#3273dc", "#ff3860", "#ffdd57"];
    let dataTotal = 0;
    const arrWithSum = [0, 0, 0];

    if (data.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
      dataTotal += 1;
      switch (data[i].opinion) {
        case 0:
          arrWithSum[0] += 1;
          break;
        case 1:
          arrWithSum[1] += 1;
          break;
        case 2:
          arrWithSum[2] += 1;
          break;
      }
    }

    const indexMax = _.indexOf(arrWithSum, _.max(arrWithSum));
    const arcOutMain = d3
      .arc()
      .innerRadius(45)
      .outerRadius(65)
      .startAngle(0)
      .endAngle((2 * Math.PI * arrWithSum[indexMax]) / dataTotal);

    svg
      .append("path")
      .attr("transform", "translate(65,65)")
      .attr("d", arcOutMain)
      .attr("fill", backgroundColors[indexMax]);

    const arcOutGrey = d3
      .arc()
      .innerRadius(45)
      .outerRadius(65)
      .startAngle((2 * Math.PI * arrWithSum[indexMax]) / dataTotal)
      .endAngle(2 * Math.PI);

    svg
      .append("path")
      .attr("transform", "translate(65,65)")
      .attr("d", arcOutGrey)
      .attr("fill", "#f4f5f7");

    const per = ((arrWithSum[indexMax] / dataTotal) * 100).toFixed(0);

    svg
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", 70)
      .attr("y", 70)
      .attr("fill", "#263238")
      .attr("font-size", "1.5em")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("font-family", "'Roboto',sans-serif")
      .text(per + "%");
  };
```

Comment: Most likely you don't see anything. Have you watched the DOM? Start with a good pie chart example.

Comment: Thanks. It probably would have helped if I'd explained that the chart wasn't displaying ;) I'm getting the following errors:                                                                                                                                    libs.js:20667 ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
    at Scope.$rootScope.drawInfo (app.js:4056)
    at $http.then.data (app.js:5026)
    at processQueue (libs.js:23183)
    at libs.js:23200
    at Scope.$eval (libs.js:24487)
    at Scope.$digest (libs.js:24299)
    at Scope.$apply (libs.js:24595)
    at done (libs.js:18549)

Comment: even is you get the loading of d3 fixed, you will not see anything. Find a good working example and use that code as a start.

Comment: Thanks. Your advice is the best approach. This code is completely dire (BTW I did get it working in the end, the node module path had changed from "node_modules/d3/build/d3.js", to "node_modules/d3/dist/d3.js",)